# Negative values from DFT/IDFT calculation

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

I'm creating a low-pass filter in frequency domain with 0.015 cutoff frequency and the corresponding high-pass filter like below:

```
auto getGaussianFilter(int32_t size) {
    const auto sigmaf = 0.015f*size; // cutoff freq.

    cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::zeros(size, size, CV_32FC1);

    for (auto fy = -size/2; fy < size/2; ++fy)
        for (auto fx = -size/2; fx < size/2; ++fx) 
            kernel.at<float>(fy + size/2, fx + size/2) = std::exp(-(fy*fy+fx*fx)/(2*sigmaf*sigmaf));
    return kernel;
} 

...

lowpassFilter  = getGaussianFilter(256);
highpassFilter = 1 - lowpassFilter;
```

, and these are applied to images like following snippet.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> planes { src, cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type()) }; 
std::vector<cv::Mat> fplanes { filter, filter };
cv::Mat complex, complexFilter;
cv::merge(planes, complex);
cv::merge(fplanes, complexFilter);

cv::dft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
shift(complex); // swapping quadrants
cv::mulSpectrums(complex, complexFilter, complex, cv::DFT_ROWS);
shift(complex); 
cv::idft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
```

Input images are 256x256 and in logarithmic scale, and the low-pass filter is applied to the square of the high-pass filtered input images.

And then I want to take a square root of the outcome of the final idft,
but it contains negative values; thus, several NaN values appear.

```
applyFilter(src, dst, highpassFilter);
cv::pow(dst, 2, dst);
applyFilter(dst, dst, lowpassFilter);
cv::sqrt(dst, dst);  // NaN !
```

Why are there negative values, and how can I deal with them in order to take the square root ?

---

**EDIT**: added the code of `shift`

```
void shift(cv::Mat& src) {
    src = src(cv::Rect(0, 0, src.cols & -2, src.rows & -2)); 
    const auto cy = src.rows/2, cx = src.cols/2;
    cv::Mat q0(src, cv::Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));
    cv::Mat q1(src, cv::Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));
    cv::Mat q2(src, cv::Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));
    cv::Mat q3(src, cv::Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy));
    cv::Mat tmp;
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);
 }
```

Comment: If the input doesn't have negative values, applying a Gaussian filter will not introduce negative values. So we are either talking about a bug in your code (check intermediate values!), or values that are just below 0 due to numerical inaccuracy (did you look for those negative values? How big are they?). In the latter case, simply clip at 0 (set negative values to 0).

Comment: Do check also that your filtering is correct. Is the image `complex` you sent into `idft` actually symmetric? Does the `shift` function work in-place?

Comment: The negative values are not small, so I think numerical inaccuracy is not the cause. Also, the square cannot contain negative values, the way of shifting quadrants is the same as the official example, and I have checked that the filter doesn't include negative values and that each filtering looks correct by normalization and cv::imshow ...

Comment: When I run simple mutual transformation with no filtering, there were only very small negative values like `-1e-5`, which might be due to numerical inaccuracy as you said. So the filtering is probably incorrect; however, the values of the filter range from 0 to 1 and what I have to do is just element-wise multiplication, so I have no idea so far..

Comment: ahh, the magnitude of the final `complex` with no `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT` looks a desirable output. However, I'm confused. Doesn't the result of `cv::idft` with `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT` is an appropriately transformed real matrix ?

Comment: Try `cv::multiply` instead of `cv::mulSpectrums`. The latter seems to do something special with CCS-packed arrays, which you have not. The `cv::DFT_ROWS` flag is wrong too. The IDFT with a real output simply ignores the imaginary part. It's not the same as taking the magnitude. That your magnitude is correct but you have an unwanted phase component indicates that the multiplication is wrong, your filter is shifted. Either an issue with `mulSpectrums` or with `shift`.

Comment: `cv::multiply` wasn't a solution, and I think my `shift` is definitely correct. I found several codes taking the magnitude or abs of the result of the idft ([1](http://vgg.fiit.stuba.sk/2012-05/frequency-domain-filtration/), [2](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Signal_Processing_with_NumPy_Fourier_Transform_FFT_DFT_2.php)), and lots of codes normalizing them between 0 and 1; I guess the raw outcome of the idft can naturally contain negative values and  I have to do something like them in order to squeeze it into an appropriate range... How do you think about that ?

Comment: Post your shift function, I think that is where the error is. If the frequency-domain signal is not perfectly conjugate symmetric, the time-domain signal will not be purely real. This is what is happening to you, according to your comments. One more thing: is `size` you pass to the `getGaussianFilter` function even or odd? That function only produces a symmetric kernel if `size` is odd.

Comment: Your link #1 is the code you seem to have used as a starting point. The fact that they need normalization and to compute magnitude shows they don't know what they're doing. Sorry... The IDFT of a conjugate symmetric frequency spectrum is real. There might be an imaginary component due to rounding error, but that can be ignored. Just taking the real part of the IDFT is sufficient. If you start with a real-valued image/signal, your DFT will be conjugate symmetric. And if your frequency-domain filter is constructed properly, that property is preserved.

Comment: I see...I’m catching on. I pasted the code of `shift`, and because the height and width of the input are currently even, `size` have to be even. You mean, I need to make the input size odd so that `size` can be odd ?

Comment: I was wrong, your `getGaussianFilter` function seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't catch this one until the third or fourth read through your code...

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> fplanes { filter, filter };
cv::merge(fplanes, complexFilter);
```

You create a complex-valued filter here, which is not conjugate symmetric. Applying this filter creates a frequency spectrum which is not conjugate symmetric, and hence you get a non-real inverse transform.

What you want to do is have a purely real filter:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> fplanes { filter, cv::Mat::zeros(filter(), filter()) };
cv::merge(fplanes, complexFilter);
```

Think of frequency-domain filters in terms of a magnitude and a phase (rather than a real and imaginary component). The magnitude changes how you change the amplitude of each frequency component in your image, the phase shifts each frequency component. In general (except in very specific cases) you do not want to shift frequency components in your image, as it will mess up your image. Thus, keep the phase of your frequency-domain filters at 0. A zero phase means that each value is non-negative and real.

That said, your sequence of shifting the frequency spectrum of the image, applying the filter, and shifting back:

```
cv::dft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
shift(complex); // swapping quadrants
cv::mulSpectrums(complex, complexFilter, complex, cv::DFT_ROWS);
shift(complex); 
cv::idft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
```

is identical to simply shifting the filter:

```
cv::dft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
shift(complexFilter); // swapping quadrants
cv::mulSpectrums(complex, complexFilter, complex, 0);
cv::idft(complex, complex, cv::DFT_SCALE | cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
```

Note also that I replaced `cv::DFT_ROWS` with 0. According to [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3ab38646463c59bf0ce962a9d51db64f), that flag indicates that each image row is an independent 1D transform. My guess is that this only matters for CCS-packed matrices, but it's better to leave it out anyway.

Comment: I get what you mean (at least in theory), and `lowpassFilter` now looks work fine; however, did you verify the corresponding `highpassFIlter` ( `1-lowpassFilter`) ? I can see there are still not small negative values..., though I confirmed it contains only non-negative and real values.

Comment: A high-pass filtered image typically has negative values. But it should be real valued. With a high-pass filter you set the 0 frequency to 0. This is the D.C. component. Setting it to zero means that the image in the spatial domain will have a 0 mean. So necessarily you'll have lots of negative values. To prevent that, set the one pixel in the middle of `highlassFilter` to 1.

Comment: In other words: setting the 0 frequency to 0 is equivalent to subtracting the mean pixel intensity from each pixel.

Comment: As you're saying, **almost all** the negative values are removed by setting the central pixel of the `highpassFilter` to 1 when the width and height of input are odd and the four pixels around the center to 1 when even !! But a really few (not small) negative values are still remaining...

Comment: Do you have any clue to this ?

Comment: Yes, I can make a trivial example where removing low (but not 0) frequencies yields negative values. I guess there is no guarantee for a high-pass filter to not introduce negative values.

Comment: So, in that case, what should I do to keep the range non-negative..., taking the absolute value ? or is there no way to do so ?

Comment: Add a constant? `signal -= min(signal)`.

Comment: True, and sorry for my unclear question. What should I do to keep the original range of values ? For example, when the input range is [0, 255], how can I get the output ranging 0-255, which, as it is, is a grayscale  image without any extra operation ?  Adding a min value suffices for that purpose ?

Comment: I presume that, since you're reducing frequency power, you're reducing signal amplitude. If this is indeed the case, adding a value to shift the range to positive values should not extend those past the input range. It makes sense, but I haven't seen a proof. :)

Comment: That's true ! I'm now much clearer about frequency-domain filtering, I guess. Thanks a lot for your awesome answer, really helping me !!